# Rectangular coordinates transform in polar coordinates $\int_{0}^2\int_0^{x} f(x,y) \,dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

If i have this integral in rectangular coordinates and i want to transform in polar coordinates
$$\int_{0}^2\int_0^{x} f(x,y) \,dy\, d x$$

The limits in $\displaystyle 0\le\theta\le\frac\pi4 $  but in $r$,the limits are $0$ to ? $ 2\sec[\theta]=r$ because $x=2 $ is equal to  $2\sec[\theta]=r$.

Comment: Try graphically shading in the region you are integrating over.  Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are integrating over a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$ and $(2,2)$. This is bounded on the right by $x = 2$; in polarese that is $r\cos(\theta) = 2$ so  your integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{2\sec(\theta)} f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta) r dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: That inner integral should be $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\sec \theta}$, and the $\sec\theta$ should not be part of the integrand.

Comment: why you add $Sec[\theta]$ in the integral? for the $rCos[\theta]=2$?

Comment: @DanielORTIZ : I already covered this.

Comment: is $o=<r<=2Sec[\theta]$ frist limit?

Comment: @DanielORTIZ : Yes.

Comment: This got edited and the edit was incorrect. I have put it back./